# Cannot create google cloud sql instance using gcloud cli because it is taking too long

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am running the following command using the gcloud cli tool...

```
gcloud sql instances create sql-db-1 --database-version=MYSQL_8_0 --region=us-central --tier=db-f1-micro
```

It sits in the terminal for a long time with the following output...

```
Creating new cloud sql instance...
```

and then finally fails with...

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) Operation https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project/operations/0d9534c4-9c70-4a77-86a9-ae5c6d3b5fd8 is taking longer than expected. You can continue waiting for the operation by running `gcloud beta sql operations wait --project my-project 0d9534c4-9c70-4a77-86a9-ae5c6d3b5fd8`
Status : FAIL 1 b''
```

This same command was working for me reliably, and then all of a sudden it just started doing this.

Comment: When you run the suggested `gcloud beta sql operations wait --project my-project 0d9534c4-9c70-4a77-86a9-ae5c6d3b5fd8` command what is the result? Does the SQL instance eventually get created?

Comment: I’ve replicated your command line from Cloud SDK in my local machine, and I also get the same error, but, at the end, the instance is created as shown in the GCP SQL Dashboard. I’m going to go further, but let me know if you could create the instance even with the error.

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez Yes after checking my instance was also created, even though an error was listed on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the command line, it creates the Cloud SQL instance, but the CLI throws an ERROR making you think that this wasn’t created; so I opened an [issue tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/223669458) for you.

Meanwhile you can also run after the error:

`gcloud beta sql operations wait --project my-project xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

And wait for the operation to complete. After that, you must see STATUS as DONE:

```
NAME                                  TYPE    START                          END                            ERROR  STATUS
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             CREATE  2022-03-09T21:53:40.532+00:00  2022-03-09T22:06:53.389+00:00  -      DONE
```

When you open this link in the ERROR:

`https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project/operations/0d9534c4-9c70-4a77-86a9-ae5c6d3b5fd8`

You will get:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlOperationsService.Get"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy locally to mimic what Cloud Run does for.

1. Download the latest release [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/releases/tag/v1.29.0)
2. Make sure you have a valid set of gcloud credentials (i.e., `gcloud auth login`)
3. Start the proxy in a Terminal with something like this:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-project:my-region:my-instance -dir ./cloudsql
```

Then the Proxy will create a Unix socket at `./cloudsql/my-project:my-region:my-instance`.

Note: to make this most like Cloud Run, you can always create a `/cloudsql` directory at the root.